# Serial port timeout- 10 seconds, but getting less samples than expected/desired

Tags: matlab, serial-port, nios

I have the following error while trying to access serial port data sent from Nios II UART: The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period or A timeout occurred before the Terminator was reached.

The above error occurs when I set the timeout to be smaller than 10 seconds, say 2 seconds, or 6 or 8 etc.

```
set(s,'BaudRate',115200,'timeout',10); %timeout is in seconds.
```

If I set the timeout to be as '10' or larger, I did not get the timeout error, however, with this timeout, the sample rate is 0.067Hz and the total number of samples I can obtain is only 493 in 120 minutes which is far too less. In similar system with timeout set to 2 seconds, we can get 46253 samples in 120 minutes with sample rate= 5Hz. (this worked previously when no Nios system is used, just FPGA)

What I think: I am getting so less samples because the Matlab needs to wait longer now compared to previous system where no Nios is used.

What I dont know and need your opinion: how to increase the number of samples to be received? 
how to increase the sample rate?

What is in my system (in C Code) : In main, the main calls for function "uart_multiple", I have 12 sets of data to be sent to the serial port, each set of data has 10 elements ('n' represents 10 bytes, one element is ONE byte), so I transmit one set of data one by one.

I suspect this could be the cause of low sample rate, but I am not sure.

Do you think we can transmit all 12 sets at the same time to avoid this issue?

If it is, what should I do to transmit all 12 sets at the same time?

```
int main (){
uart_multiple (&txdata1, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata2, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata3, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata4, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata5, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata6, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata7, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata8, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata9, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata10, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata11, n);
uart_multiple (&txdata12, n);}
```